# If $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} < 1-\frac 1n$ for almost every n implies $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove or give a counter-example for:

If for a given $(a_n)$ for almost every $n$:
$$\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} < 1-\frac 1n$$
then:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$
Converges.

I know $(1-\frac 1n)\to1$, so if $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ has a finite limit it must be smaller than 1, which will tell us the series converges from the root convergence test. But I'm struggling to find an example for an $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ that follows the above condition and doesn't have a finite limit.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The problem is not the finite limit; it is its relationship with 1.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ is a counterexample if we modify the first few terms, as we can prove
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n}}<1-\frac{1}{n}
$$
for $n$ large enough.

$\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n}}<1-\frac{1}{n}$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{n}\ln\frac{1}{n}-\ln(1-\frac{1}{n})<0$. Now we investigate the function $f(x)=x\ln x-\ln(1-x)$. Its derivative $f'(x)=\ln x+1+\frac{1}{1-x}$ tends to $-\infty$ when $x\to0^+$, so $f'(x)$ must be negative in a right neighborhood of $0$. Since $f(x)\to0$ as $x\to 0^+$, we see that $f(x)$ must be negative in a right neighborhood of $0$, say $(0,x_0)$. Then
$$
\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n}}<1-\frac{1}{n}
$$
for $n>\frac{1}{x_0}$.

Answer (score 2):

The proposition is false:

Set $a_n:=\frac 1n, n\in \Bbb N$. Then, finally $(\frac 1n)^{\frac 1n}<1-\frac 1n$, for $(1-\frac 1n)^n\to \frac 1e$ and $\frac 1n \to 0$, so $(1-\frac 1n)^n>\frac 1n$ finally. Although $\sum a_n$ diverges.